# How to fix type error in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following function in a google app script running on a google sheet.

```
function GetRecords(username) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var displaySheet = ss.getSheetByName("DISPLAY SHEETS");
  var getLastRow =  displaySheet.getLastRow();
  var gradeArray = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
    var gradeSheetName = displaySheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    var gradeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(gradeSheetName);
    var getLastRowGrade =  gradeSheet.getLastRow();
    for(var y = 2; y <= getLastRowGrade; y++)
    {
      if(gradeSheet.getRange(y, 1).getValue().toUpperCase() == username.toUpperCase())
      {
        var grade = gradeSheet.getRange(y, 2).getValue();
        gradeArray.push([username.toUpperCase(), gradeSheetName, grade]);
      }
    }
  }
  return gradeArray;  
}
```

It was working fine up until yesterday, where it now returns the following type error:

```
TypeError: gradeSheet.getRange(...).getValue(...).toUpperCase is not a function
    at GetRecords(Code:17:47)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

`getValue()` can return Number, Date, Boolean, or String data type depending on the cell value. Your cell contained a non-string value so it cannot be converted to uppercase.

You could manually convert the value to String first:

```
gradeSheet.getRange(y, 1).getValue().toString().toUpperCase()
```

**Sample:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Class Range | getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

Comment: Please let us know if the answer addressed your issue. Thank you.